# Differences between AWS Global and AWS China

Tags: amazon-web-services

[Not sure this is the correct forum for this question, but I'll give it a shot.]

I'm looking at duplicating an existing solution built on AWS into an AWS China account. From what I've read in [AWS' getting started blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/enterprise-strategy/getting-started-with-aws-services-in-aws-china-beijing-region-and-aws-china-ningxia-region/) and [AWS China's list of services per region](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/about-aws/regional-product-services/), it seems to me that deploying a solution in Beijing or Ningxia using the AWS services we're used to and dependent on would be feasible. But since you cannot create an AWS China account without having a business license (which seems to be a topic in itself, hmm), it seems impossible to actually try things out to get a feel for if there are any differences. I also cannot seem to find any blog posts with testimonies, experiences from developers or architects who've done this, which is surprising.

Basically I want to understand if taking an existing solution built on AWS and setting it up on Chinese infrastructure is straightforward or if I should expect some differences in how things work etc. I know that AWS does not operate these two regions themselves, but through Chinese partner companies. But I'm not sure if the service capabilities, APIs etc are identical (even including the timing of releases of new versions etc).

The only real limitations I can find on the AWS blog is that the free tier is not available, and that EC2 classic instances is not supported. But let's say I have a solution using very stadnard AWS services like Cloudfront, S3, DynamoDB, Lambda, ECS, Elastic Beanstalk, Cognito, KMS etc. Will it be fairly simple to migrate it to an AWS China account or should I expect a struggle?

Comment: Were you able to find any answer? Can you share it? @JHH

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the difference, basically AWS China and AWS Global are two seperate cloud and they are not connected to earch other, thus they will have separate Marketplace,Endpoints and ARNs, different service capablities etc.  However those differences are not capatured in such details in official AWS documentation.

For example most security related features, landing zone related feature are not available in AWS China.   I have tried to customize some AWS global solutions to China, and met lot of issues and challenges, so plug and play won't work here.  The best way is to have some parnters or local presence to overcome those challenges especially the team with similar capabilities.

Comment: for example, cross-region cross-account S3 replication in China is not supported which it is supported in AWS Global.  Config aggregator is not supported in China. There is much more.